# How to update a param value using Freshdesk Serverless App on Ticket Create

Tags: serverless, freshdesk

In freshdesk server-less app when we make callbacks onTicketCreate() how to update a param value in the payload args["data"]?

Use case :

Based on some logic I need to update the args["data"]["ticket"]["some param"] value.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [update ticket API](https://developer.freshdesk.com/api/#update_ticket) to update any of the fields.

You could do this easily using the [Request package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) (or the even the node HTTP client if you dare)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your use case correctly, here is what you meant:

Every time a ticket is created you want to update the values of Installation parameters(iparams).

In your `server/server.js`'s *onTicketCreateHandler* function will receive a [payload](https://developers.freshdesk.com/v2/docs/product-events/#onticketcreate). According to the payload your iparams values will be received in `payload.iparams['your_iparam']` but **not** as `payload.data["ticket"]["your_iparam"]`.

That said, all now you have to do is assign new value to `payload.iparams["your_iparam"]` in *onTicketCreateHandler* function:

```
payload.iparams["your_iparam"] = your_new_value;
```